# How to make multiple HTMLpurifier configurations?

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I need 3 different configurations for different situations. Sometimes I need it to filter everything out and on other forms I need it to allow somethings. However I've noticed that any new ones defined, make the changes for all of the other configurations :(

```
//this isn't working right
$default_cfg = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($default_cfg);

$purifier_minimal_cfg = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier_minimal_cfg->set('HTML.Allowed', 'em,strong,p,br');
$purifier_minimal_cfg->set('AutoFormat.AutoParagraph', true);
$purifier_minimal_html = new HTMLPurifier($purifier_minimal_cfg);

$purifier_featured_html_cfg = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier_featured_html_cfg->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href],abbr[title],blockquote,br,cite,code,del,div,em,hr,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,img[alt|src],li,ol,p,s,small,span,strong,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,tr,ul');
$purifier_featured_html_cfg->set('AutoFormat.AutoParagraph', true);
$purifier_featured_html = new HTMLPurifier($purifier_featured_html_cfg);

if ($purifier_featured_html->purify($html_string) == $purifier->purify($html_string))
echo 'this is bad!';
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work OK for me:

```
ezyang@sabre:~/Dev/htmlpurifier$ cat test.php 
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once 'library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

//this isn't working right
$default_cfg = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($default_cfg);

$purifier_minimal_cfg = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier_minimal_cfg->set('HTML.Allowed', 'em,strong,p,br');
$purifier_minimal_cfg->set('AutoFormat.AutoParagraph', true);
$purifier_minimal_html = new HTMLPurifier($purifier_minimal_cfg);

$purifier_featured_html_cfg = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier_featured_html_cfg->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href],abbr[title],blockquote,br,cite,code,del,div,em,hr,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,img[alt|src],li,ol,p,s,small,span,strong,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,tr,ul');
$purifier_featured_html_cfg->set('AutoFormat.AutoParagraph', true);
$purifier_featured_html = new HTMLPurifier($purifier_featured_html_cfg);

$html_string = "<abbr>asdf</abbr>";
if ($purifier_featured_html->purify($html_string) == $purifier->purify($html_string))
echo 'this is bad!';
ezyang@sabre:~/Dev/htmlpurifier$ php test.php
ezyang@sabre:~/Dev/htmlpurifier$
```